# What happened to 69ers?

Tags: mountain-bike

[image]

For a year or two, I remember there being a pretty big buzz around 29" front wheel, 26" rear wheel mountain bikes.  They seem to have fallen off the face of the earth.  What happened?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At the time that 69ers came along, 29ers were still struggling to gain mainstream acceptance and 69ers simply didn't offer enough benefit, if any, to really interest the masses. I always felt that 69ers, especially hardtails, did more to combine the disadvantages of each platform rather than the advantages and so did many others. There just wasn't a compelling reason to mess with such a niche bike at a time when you could count all the 29er suspension forks and tires *combined* with just your fingers.
Ultimately as we all know, 29ers did gain mainstream acceptance, and when there was room for a "middle ground" platform 650b's filled the gap. It doesn't mean the configuration wont come back- I think it still offers potential benefit in a full suspension configuration, but the first wave of 69ers was not a success. At the time it was an untested platform based on an untested platform that typically cost more than all the other comparable bikes due to the small production runs.

Comment: I have to add, they just look "wrong".... require carrying 2 spare tubes, and having two spare tires. Murphy will ensure if you only have one, it will be the wrong one......